# How do I reduce values in a column to a single value SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, Users and Orders. I want to retrieve the names of users who have made more than £100 worth of orders.

Users:

```
user_id (PK)
firstname
```

Orders:

```
order_id (PK)
user_id (FK)
amount
```

How can I first retrieve orders by a `user_id` and then reduce all these orders into a single value (sum of all order amounts)?

So something along the lines of

```
Select user.firstname 
From .....
Where orderTotal > 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `group by` and `having`:

```
select u.user_id, u.name
from orders o join
     users o
     on o.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.user_id, u.name
having sum(amount) > 100;
```